# c:forEach displays everything in a single table row

Tags: jsp, html-table, jstl

At the moment I am doing a project in which I need to display information in a column from my database, but for some reason they are displayed in a row. Now the display looks like this:

[image]

I am also attaching the code from my jsp page :

```html
<table border="1"
       cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"
       style="font-size: small; line-height: 100px; border-color: #D1EEEE">
    <tr bgcolor="#DCDCDC" align="left" style="border-color: #838B83">
        <th width="250px">Discipline</th>
        <th width="100px">Mark</th>
    </tr>

    <c:forEach items="${Disc}" var="Dis">
        <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">${Dis.discipline}</td>
        <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">0</td>
    </c:forEach>

    <td/>
</table>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: When posting a question, make sure you only add _relevant_ tags. This question has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boostrap is not a bad idea (mentioned and linked in Bhola Galy's answer). But if you definitely need to use a table for some reason, know that `<tr>` stands for "table row." A `<td>` tag and closing tag enclose a cell of data. A `<th>` is a table header.

[MDN's article on table basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics#allowing_cells_to_span_multiple_rows_and_columns) is useful.

Not sure if this is exactly what you mean, but below I've added `<tr>`s wrapping what you might want as a row.
Within a single `<tr>`, elements placed there will fall into a row.

This example is only a subset of your snippet, but may show the principle.

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"
                style="font-size: small; line-height: 25px; border-color: #D1EEEE">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">(Name here)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">(Surname here)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Group</th>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">(Group here)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date of enrollment</th>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">(Date here)</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Most Internet users are on devices that differ greatly in screen size. By default Bootstrap acknowledges the need for responsiveness to differing screen sizes.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the problem is not in the part where the first name, surname, etc., but where the disciplines and grades are, see how everything was skewed there ....

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a solution - it was obvious. It was necessary to: Add `<tr>` and `</tr>` to the loop. Remove the obscure `<td/>`.

```html
               <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 50px 0 0 0">
                            <table border="1"
                                   cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"
                                   style="font-size: small; line-height: 100px; border-color: #D1EEEE">
                                <tr bgcolor="#DCDCDC" align="left" style="border-color: #838B83">
                                    <th width="250px">Discipline</th>
                                    <th width="100px">Mark</th>
                                </tr>


                                    <c:forEach items="${Disc}" var="Dis">
                                <tr>
                                <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">${Dis.discipline}</td>
                                        <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">0</td>
                                </tr>
                                </c:forEach>
                                
                            </table>
```